# How to dissolve overlapping distance isochrones

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, merge, isochrone

For my master's thesis I need to create distance isochrones (10/20/30/../100km) around certain coordinates. In my case they overlap and I want the overlapping parts to dissolve, but at the same time keep the distance intervals of 10km. Is there a smooth way to do this?

Here is the example pic of the overlapping isochrones:

[image]

You can see there is an underlying isochrone with the according distances.. is there someway to merge them and still get the according distance intervals?

Comment: Use `select by expression` to select those features with the same attribute. Than dissolve the selected features only.